# my ListView open's in "new window"

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

Hi i'm new to android development and i have a problem showing a contacts list in listview inside a fragment with navigation drawer

the list actualy is working but it open's in "new window" instead of inside the fragmet

sorry for my bad english

in my src folder i have:
- MainActivity.java
- HomeFragment.java
- FindPeopleFragment.java
- ContactsActivity.java
.....

in my layout folder i have:
- activity_main.xml
- fragment_home.xml
- fragment_find_people.xml
- lv_layout.xml
.....

the code:

MainActivity.java;

```
import info.of.slidingmenu.adapter.NavDrawerListAdapter;
import info.of.slidingmenu.model.NavDrawerItem;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.MatrixCursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {


        private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
        private ListView mDrawerList;
        private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

        // nav drawer title
        private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

        // used to store app title
        private CharSequence mTitle;

        // slide menu items
        private String[] navMenuTitles;
        private TypedArray navMenuIcons;

        private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
        private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;

        SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter;
        MatrixCursor mMatrixCursor;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

            // load slide menu items
            navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

            // nav drawer icons from resources
            navMenuIcons = getResources()
                    .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

            mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);

            navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

            // adding nav drawer items to array
            // Home
            navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)));
            // Find People
            navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));
            // Photos
            navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(2, -1)));
            // Communities, Will add a counter here
            navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(3, -1), true, "22"));
            // Pages
            navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[4], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(4, -1)));
            // What's hot, We  will add a counter here
            navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[5], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(5, -1), true, "50+"));


            // Recycle the typed array
            navMenuIcons.recycle();

            mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

            // setting the nav drawer list adapter
            adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                    navDrawerItems);
            mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

            // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
            getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

            mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                    R.drawable.ic_drawer, //nav menu toggle icon
                    R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for accessibility
                    R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for accessibility
                    ) {
                public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                    getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                    // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
                    invalidateOptionsMenu();
                }

                public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                    getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                    // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
                    invalidateOptionsMenu();
                }
            };
            mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

            if (savedInstanceState == null) {
                // on first time display view for first nav item
                displayView(0);
            }

            Toast.makeText(this, "Activity created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        }


        String[] prefix = new String[]{"0610","0611","0613","0615","0616","0618","0622","0623",
                                        "0624","0628","0641","0642","0648","0650","0651","0652",
                                        "0653","0654","0655","0658","0659","0661","0662","0666",
                                        "0667","0668","0670","0671","0672","0673","0676","0677",
                                        "0678"," ","0612","0614","0617","0619","0620","0644","0645",
                                        "0649","0656","0657","0660","0663","0664","0665","0669","0674"
                                        ,"0675","0679"," ","0600","0601","0602","0603","0606","0626",
                                        "0627","0629","0630","0633","0634","0635","0638","0699"," ",
                                        "0640","0646","0647"," ","0526","0527","0540","0546","0547",
                                        "0533","0534","0550","0553"};

        String[] provider = new String[]{"iam","meditel","inwi","modem_inwi","bayn"};

        public String getProvider(String num){
            //0642212125
            //+212642848
            String ns;
            String msg = "";
            if(num.indexOf("+") != -1){
                ns = "0" +num.substring(4, 7);
            }else{
                ns = num.substring(0,4);
            }
            int j = 0;
            boolean found = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < prefix.length-1; i++) {
                if(prefix[i].equals(ns) & found == false){
                    msg = provider[j] ;
                    found = true;
                    if (msg == "inwi"){
                        ImageView Imgview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgViewOperator2);
                        Imgview.setImageResource(R.drawable.inwi);
                    }
                    else if (msg == "meditel"){
                        ImageView Imgview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgViewOperator2);
                        Imgview.setImageResource(R.drawable.meditel);
                    }
                    else if (msg == "bayn"){
                        ImageView Imgview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgViewOperator2);
                        Imgview.setImageResource(R.drawable.bayn);
                    }
                    else if (msg == "iam"){
                        ImageView Imgview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgViewOperator2);
                        Imgview.setImageResource(R.drawable.iam);
                    }
                    else if (msg == "modem_inwi"){
                        ImageView Imgview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgViewOperator2);
                        Imgview.setImageResource(R.drawable.modem_inwi);
                    }
                    else{
                        ImageView Imgview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgViewOperator2);
                        Imgview.setImageResource(R.drawable.none);
                    }
                    //document.getElementById("src_img").innerHTML = "<img src='images/puces/" + provider[j] + ".png' alt='' />";
                    //              break;
                }
                else if(prefix[i] == " " & found == false){
                    j += 1;
                    //              msg = j + " " + ns + " " + provider[j];
                }
                else if(i == prefix.length & found == false){
                    msg = "";
                    //document.getElementById("src_img").innerHTML = "<img src='images/puces/none.png' alt='' />";
                }
            };
            return msg;
        }

        /**
         * Slide menu item click listener
         * */
        private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
        ListView.OnItemClickListener {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                    long id) {
                // display view for selected nav drawer item
                displayView(position);

            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
            if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
                return true;
            }
            // Handle action bar actions click
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_settings:
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }
        }

        /* *
         * Called when invalidateOptionsMenu() is triggered
         */
        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
            boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
            menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
            return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
        }

        /**
         * Diplaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
         * */
        private void displayView(int position) {
            // update the main content by replacing fragments
            Fragment fragment = null;
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                fragment = new HomeFragment();
                break;
            case 1:
                fragment = new FindPeopleFragment();
                break;
            case 2:
                fragment = new PhotosFragment();
                break;
            case 3:
                fragment = new CommunityFragment();
                break;
            case 4:
                fragment = new PagesFragment();
                break;
            case 5:
                fragment = new WhatsHotFragment();
                break;

            default:
                break;
            }

            if (fragment != null) {
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

                // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
                mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
                mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
                setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
                Toast.makeText(this, "mDrawerList Position: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            } else {
                // error in creating fragment
                Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
            }
        }



        @Override
        public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
            mTitle = title;
            getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
        }

        /**
         * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
         * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
         */

        @Override
        protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
            // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
            mDrawerToggle.syncState();
        }

        @Override
        public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
            super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
            // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
            mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        }


    }
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <!-- Listview to display slider menu -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@color/list_divider"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"        
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
        android:background="@color/list_background"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

FindPeopleFragment.java:

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class FindPeopleFragment extends Fragment  {

public FindPeopleFragment(){}


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_find_people, container, false);

        Intent myIntent = new Intent((MainActivity)getActivity(), ContactsActivity.class);
        getActivity().startActivity(myIntent);



        return rootView;
    }


}
```

fragment_find_people.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

ContactsActivity.java:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.MatrixCursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class ContactsActivity extends Activity {

    SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter;
    MatrixCursor mMatrixCursor;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_find_people);

        // The contacts from the contacts content provider is stored in this cursor
        mMatrixCursor = new MatrixCursor(new String[] { "_id","name","photo","details"} );

        // Adapter to set data in the listview
        mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getBaseContext(),
            R.layout.lv_layout,
            null,
            new String[] { "name","photo","details"},
            new int[] { R.id.tv_name,R.id.iv_photo,R.id.tv_details}, 0);

        // Getting reference to listview
        ListView lstContacts = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

        // Setting the adapter to listview
        lstContacts.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        // Creating an AsyncTask object to retrieve and load listview with contacts
        ListViewContactsLoader listViewContactsLoader = new ListViewContactsLoader();

        // Starting the AsyncTask process to retrieve and load listview with contacts
        listViewContactsLoader.execute();
    }

    /** An AsyncTask class to retrieve and load listview with contacts */
    private class ListViewContactsLoader extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Cursor>{

        @Override
        protected Cursor doInBackground(Void... params) {
            Uri contactsUri = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;

            // Querying the table ContactsContract.Contacts to retrieve all the contacts
            Cursor contactsCursor = getContentResolver().query(contactsUri, null, null, null,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC ");

            if(contactsCursor.moveToFirst()){
                do{
                    long contactId = contactsCursor.getLong(contactsCursor.getColumnIndex("_ID"));

                    Uri dataUri = ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI;

                    // Querying the table ContactsContract.Data to retrieve individual items like
                    // home phone, mobile phone, work email etc corresponding to each contact
                    Cursor dataCursor = getContentResolver().query(dataUri, null,
                                        ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + "=" + contactId,
                                        null, null);

                    String displayName="";
                    String nickName="";
                    String homePhone="";
                    String mobilePhone="";
                    String workPhone="";
                    String otherPhone="";
                    String photoPath="" + R.drawable.blank;
                    byte[] photoByte=null;
                    String homeEmail="";
                    String workEmail="";
                    String companyName="";
                    String title="";

                    if(dataCursor.moveToFirst()){
                        // Getting Display Name
                        displayName = dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME ));
                        do{

                            // Getting NickName
                            if(dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndex("mimetype")).equals(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Nickname.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE))
                                nickName = dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndex("data1"));

                            // Getting Phone numbers
                            if(dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndex("mimetype")).equals(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)){
                                switch(dataCursor.getInt(dataCursor.getColumnIndex("data2"))){
                                    case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_HOME :
                                        homePhone = dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndex("data1"));
                                        break;
                                    case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE :
                                        mobilePhone = dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndex("data1"));
                                        break;
                                    case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_WORK :
                                        workPhone = dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndex("data1"));
                                        break;
                                    case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_OTHER :
                                        otherPhone = dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndex("data1"));
                                        break;
                                }
                            }

                            // Getting EMails
                            if(dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndex("mimetype")).equals(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE ) ) {
                                switch(dataCursor.getInt(dataCursor.getColumnIndex("data2"))){
                                    case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE_HOME :
                                        homeEmail = dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndex("data1"));
                                        break;
                                    case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE_WORK :
                                        workEmail = dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndex("data1"));
                                        break;
                                }
                            }

                            // Getting Organization details
                            if(dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndex("mimetype")).equals(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)){
                                companyName = dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndex("data1"));
                                title = dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndex("data4"));
                            }

                            // Getting Photo
                            if(dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndex("mimetype")).equals(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)){
                                photoByte = dataCursor.getBlob(dataCursor.getColumnIndex("data15"));

                                if(photoByte != null) {
                                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(photoByte, 0, photoByte.length);

                                    // Getting Caching directory
                                    File cacheDirectory = getBaseContext().getCacheDir();

                                    // Temporary file to store the contact image
                                    File tmpFile = new File(cacheDirectory.getPath() + "/wpta_"+contactId+".png");

                                    // The FileOutputStream to the temporary file
                                    try {
                                        FileOutputStream fOutStream = new FileOutputStream(tmpFile);

                                        // Writing the bitmap to the temporary file as png file
                                        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100, fOutStream);

                                        // Flush the FileOutputStream
                                        fOutStream.flush();

                                        //Close the FileOutputStream
                                        fOutStream.close();

                                    } catch (Exception e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                    photoPath = tmpFile.getPath();
                                }
                            }
                        }while(dataCursor.moveToNext());
                        String details = "";

                        // Concatenating various information to single string
                        if(homePhone != null && !homePhone.equals("") )
                            details = "HomePhone : " + homePhone + "\n";
                        if(mobilePhone != null && !mobilePhone.equals("") )
                            details += "MobilePhone : " + mobilePhone + "\n";
                        if(workPhone != null && !workPhone.equals("") )
                            details += "WorkPhone : " + workPhone + "\n";
                        if(otherPhone != null && !otherPhone.equals("") )
                            details += "OtherPhone : " + otherPhone + "\n";
                        if(nickName != null && !nickName.equals("") )
                            details += "NickName : " + nickName + "\n";
                        if(homeEmail != null && !homeEmail.equals("") )
                            details += "HomeEmail : " + homeEmail + "\n";
                        if(workEmail != null && !workEmail.equals("") )
                            details += "WorkEmail : " + workEmail + "\n";
                        if(companyName != null && !companyName.equals("") )
                            details += "CompanyName : " + companyName + "\n";
                        if(title != null && !title.equals("") )
                            details += "Title : " + title + "\n";

                        // Adding id, display name, path to photo and other details to cursor
                        mMatrixCursor.addRow(new Object[]{ Long.toString(contactId),displayName,photoPath,details});
                    }
                }while(contactsCursor.moveToNext());
            }
            return mMatrixCursor;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Cursor result) {
            // Setting the cursor containing contacts to listview
            mAdapter.swapCursor(result);
        }
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

lv_layout.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_photo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="4dp"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_details"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="4dp"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="info.of.slidingmenu"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme" android:logo="@drawable/logo">
        <activity
            android:name="info.of.slidingmenu.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
                android:name="info.of.slidingmenu.ContactsActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name" 
                android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

any help please!!

Comment: just post the relevant code....

Comment: i think is all relevant

Comment: please help me
i appreciate your efforts

Comment: the listview inside fragment_find_people.xml the layout of FindPeopleFragment.java and the code of the contact list is in ContactsActivity.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is with your `FindPeopleFragment` , your are starting an `Activity` from `onCreateView` , instead you should set the `Fragment layout` and do other process with in the `Fragment`

Move all the code from `ContactsActivity` to `FindPeopleFragment`. You can find the views in the Fragment layout from the inflated view like this

```
    // Getting reference to listview
    ListView lstContacts = (ListView) rootView .findViewById(R.id.listview);
```

Change the  `onCreateView` of `FindPeopleFragment` and do all other stuff

```
  @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_find_people, container, false);

    // Getting reference to listview
    ListView lstContacts = (ListView) rootView .findViewById(R.id.listview);

    // Setting the adapter to listview
    lstContacts.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    // add all the other code here

    return rootView;
}
```

Comment: now i get The method getBaseContext() and getContentResolver() undefined for type FindPeopleFragment    what to do ??

Comment: Use the Activity content , `getActivity()` and `getActivity().getContentResolver()`